# How to report multiple diagnostic settings for one Azure Resource in PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

So, I am working on a script that will list diagnostic settings in Azure by name and I have figured that out.  I am also looking for resources that have more than one diagnostic setting set up on them, as we only one want for each resource.

I attempted to run ($*.Count -gt 1) and ($*.Name -gt 1) but then it just lists all the resources in the subscription that have diagnostic settings assigned to them.

Here is my full line currently:

```
    $resourceId = $azResource.ResourceId
    $azDiagSettings = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $resourceId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
       # Where-Object { ($_.Name -eq 'setbypolicy_logAnalytics') }
        Where-Object { ($_.Name -gt 1) -or ($_.Name -ne 'setbypolicy') -and ($_.Name -ne     'setbypolicy_logAnalytics') }
```

Any help is appreciated.  I am relatively new with PowerShell but this one is stumping me.

Tried to find resources with more than one diagnostic setting applied, but instead got the full list of all diagnostic settings assigned

Comment: To understand what is happening replace the Where-Object with "Select-Object -Property *"    which will list all the properties.

Answer (score 0):

> To find resources with more than one diagnostic setting applied:

*I tried the below PS script to obtain the required outcome and it worked as follows.*

```
$resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "xxxxx"
foreach ($res in $resource) {
    $diagnosticSettings = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $res.ResourceId
   if ($diagnosticSettings.Count -gt 1) {
     Write-Output $res.Name
   }
 }
```

***I've taken the resource which has more than one diagnostic applied and ran the above script.***

[image]

***Output-1:***

[image]

***Now I've tried with the resource without any diagnostic settings given and no settings are obtained in the below output because it doesn't have any.***

[image]

[image]